# nextjs 12 getServerSideProps error: HttpError: cookies is not iterable at handleError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an app in the production that has a server side component. it works ok on local host but suddenly in production I see this error

```
error: HttpError: cookies is not iterable
at handleError (/usr/src/.next/server/chunks/6830.js:163:11)
at sendRequest (/usr/src/.next/server/chunks/6830.js:214:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async getServerSideProps (/usr/src/.next/server/pages/addetail/[id].js:94:32)
at async Object.renderToHTML (/usr/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:508:20)
at async doRender (/usr/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:669:38)
at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.isManualRevalidate.isManualRevalidate (/usr/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:778:28)
at async /usr/src/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:80:36 {
status: 500,
body: undefined
}
```

this is my serverside component

```
import React from 'react';
import Error from 'next/error';
import AdDetail from '../../addetail';
import { getAdDetailSSR } from '../../../components/http/fetch';

export async function getServerSideProps(props) {
  try {
    const serverResponse = await getAdDetailSSR(props.query.id);
    return { props: { serverResponse } };
  } catch (err) {
    const errorCode = err.status;
    if (errorCode === 404) {
      return { notFound: true };
    }
    return { props: { errorCode } };
  }
}

const AdDetailRout = ({ errorCode, serverResponse }) => {
  if (errorCode) {
    return <Error statusCode={errorCode} />;
  }
  return <AdDetail res={serverResponse} />;
};



export default AdDetailRout;
```

im using nextjs 12 and react 16.
I'm not even sure if this is a front-end issue but I like to understand what does it mean why its happening and how to fix this.

**update**
this is the file which handles request. my guess is if its on front end its this file since all of the serverside components(not just the one above) suddenly stopped working on production

```
import { loadFromLocalStorage, saveToLocalStorage } from './localStorage';

const DefaultHttpOptions = {
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Cache: 'no-cache',
    Cookie: 'csrftoken=SOMETHING',
  },
};

class HttpError extends Error {
  constructor(message = '', status, body, ...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.message = message;
    this.status = status;
    this.body = body;
  }
}

const buildUrlWithParams = (url, params) => {
  const newURL = new URL(url);
  Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
    newURL.searchParams.append(key, params[key]);
  });
};

const handleError = error => {
  throw new HttpError(error.message, error.status, error.body);
};

const handleSuccess = response => {
  const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
  const valueResponseMap = {
    'application/json': 'json',
    'image/jpg': 'blob',
  };
  const bodyPromise = response[valueResponseMap[contentType] || 'text']();

  return bodyPromise.then(body => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      return handleError({
        message: body.message,
        status: response.status,
        body,
      });
    }
    return body;
  });
};

const sendRequest = async (url, method, options) => {
  const { params, notSetToken, ...optionsRest } = options;
  const newUrl = params ? buildUrlWithParams(params) : url;
  const authUser = loadFromLocalStorage('user-auth');
  if (authUser) {
    DefaultHttpOptions.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${authUser.token}`;
  }
  if (notSetToken) {
    delete DefaultHttpOptions.headers.Authorization;
  }

  const httpOptions = {
    method,
    ...optionsRest,
    ...DefaultHttpOptions,
    headers: { ...DefaultHttpOptions.headers, ...optionsRest.headers },
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${newUrl}`, httpOptions);
    for (let entry of response.headers.entries()) {
      if (entry[0] === 'access-token' && authUser.token !== entry[1]) {
        saveToLocalStorage(
          {
            ...authUser,
            token: entry[1],
          },
          'user-auth'
        );
      }
    }

    return handleSuccess(response, optionsRest);
  } catch (error) {
    return handleError(error);
  }
};

const Apiurl ='MYAPIROUT';
const HttpRequestSSR = {
  get(url, options) {
    return sendRequest(Apiurl + url, 'GET', options);
  },
  post(url, options) {
    return sendRequest(Apiurl + url, 'POST', options);
  },
  put(url, options) {
    return sendRequest(Apiurl + url, 'PUT', options);
  },
  delete(url, options) {
    return sendRequest(Apiurl + url, 'DELETE', options);
  },
};

export default HttpRequestSSR;
```

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox with a running example?

Comment: thank you for your response. I'm afraid not but I edited my post and added my httpclient in utils which I think might have something to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. There was a difference between server versions of the packages and what we were using on the code. Since we used `^` on our `package.json` the server was installing the latest version of the package but in local we were using the mentioned version. Some of these packages had dependency conflict with each other so I changed the versions to exact version of the previous stable version. For example:

```
"axios": "^0.21.0",
```

to

```
"axios": "0.21.4",
```